# vs2012 DirectXMath more than one instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am playing with directx 11 (Windows SDK 8) in VS2012 on Windows 7

And i am getting this Error

```
1 IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "XMMatrixTranspose" matches the argument list:
        function "DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::CXMMATRIX M)"
        function "XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::CXMMATRIX M)"
        argument types are: (const DirectX::XMMATRIX) c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\DirectXMathMatrix.inl
```

There is nothing special in code i just include `#include <DirectXMath.h>` 
And anytime is use one of XMMatrix methods i get this

Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Windows 7 includes part of the Windows 8 DirectX 11.1 files. For example many of the header files will be included twice which will make Visual Studio give out a million warnings about it. However, that's all they are in my system. Why are you using Windows 8 SDK on Windows 7? Just out of curiosity...

I would suggest just using Windows 7 SDK on Windows 7, and Windows 8 SDK on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 SDK on Windows 7 64 bit to develop DirectX 11 apps with the new code model. I had the same problem as OP.

The solution for me was to fully specify any methods from the DirectXMath.h library (for example as DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose) when calling them.

example call:

```
m_viewMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH(position, lookAt, up);
```